# Efficiently sum max(Ai+Bj, Bi+Aj) over all i, j

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, array-algorithms

You are given two integer arrays A and B of length N. You have to find the value of two summation:

Z=Σ Σ max(Ai+Bj, Bi+Aj)

Here is my brute force algorithm

1. for loop (i to length)
2. for loop (j to length)
3. sum+=Math.max(A[i]+B[j], A[j]+B[i]);

Please tell me a better efficient algorithm for this.

Answer (score 9):

Rewrite the sum as Z = Σi Σj [max(Ai−Bi, Aj−Bj) + Bi + Bj] by using the distributive property of plus over max. Then construct C = A−B, sort it, and return Σi (2i+1)Ci + 2n Σi Bi (using zero-based indexing).

Comment: Very nice insight !

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was a very brilliant use of the distributive property

Answer (score 0):

A minor improvement I can think of is to omit the results that you already computed. This means, instead of beginning the inner loop from `0`, you can start with `j = i`. Since you already have computed the results for `j < i` in the previous loops.
To achieve this, you can change the instruction in the inner loop to the following:

```
if i != j
     sum += 2 * Math.max(A[i]+B[j], A[j]+B[i]);
else
     sum += Math.max(A[i]+B[j], A[j]+B[i]);
```

The reason is that every pair of `i` and `j` are visited twice by the loops.