# Find no. of Comparisons such that A[i] +A[j]> B[i] + B[j] where i<j

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, data-structures

I want to write an algorithm to count no. of comparisons such that A[i] +A[j]> B[i] + B[j]
where i<j in as less time as possible.

I know the Brute-Force approach for this, but it take O(n^2) time while I need to solve it in less time. I have also explored the approach based on Merge Sort, but it doesn't seem to work properly

```
#include <algorithm> // for sort

int comparisons = 0;

// sort arrays A and B in ascending order
std::sort(A.begin(), A.end());
std::sort(B.begin(), B.end());

for (int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = i+1; j < A.size(); j++) {
        if (A[i] + A[j] > B[i] + B[j]) {
            comparisons++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are sorting `A` and `B`. Is it because the problem assumes that these arrays are sorted, or because you think that the problem could be simplified by doing this? In your code, you are not using that they are sorted.

Comment: I would hope that sorting the arrays is part of the problem because it certainly changes the result.

Comment: @Damien You are (effectively) comparing two arrays in parallel, so if you mess with the order of the elements in those arrays you are potentially changing the result.

Comment: @john I discovered it just after entering the comment ! Effectively ...

Comment: What this question lacks is a clear statement of the problem being solved. That the code posted sorts the arrays is confusing.

Comment: I thought maybe the performance will increase by sorting arrays but it didn't work

Comment: and yes sorting does change the answer, so it doesn't seem to be a right approach

Comment: Here's a hint: the inequality is equivalent to `A[i] - B[i] > B[j] - A[j]`. First define `C` s.t `C[i] = B[i] - A[i]`. Iterating each index `A[i], B[i]` in parallel, all you really need to do is count the number of values `C[j]` to the right of `i` where `A[i] - B[i] > C[j]`, which gives the number pairs satisfying the inequality for index `i`. If this is done in a smart way the runtime would be `O(N*log(N))`, assuming N is the length of `A` and `B`.

Comment: cf. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69426072/efficiently-sum-maxaibj-biaj-over-all-i-j/69426350#69426350

Comment: I have done the following implementation, but it gives wrong output for some cases https://stackoverflow.com/a/75021732/20938266 such as   
std::vector<int> A = {5,10,5, 7};
std::vector<int> B = {2, 4, 6, 8};
and i can't figure why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, the relation corresponds to `C[i] > -C[j]`, where
`C[i] = A[i] - B[i]`.

The count is easy after the sorting of `C`.

We just have to pay attention to exclude the cases `i == j`, and to take into account that a direct summation doubles
the number of cases.

Complexity is dominated by the sorting: O(n logn).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int n_compar_bf (const std::vector<int>& A, const std::vector<int>& B) {
    int comparisons = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = i+1; j < A.size(); j++) {
            if (A[i] + A[j] > B[i] + B[j]) {
                comparisons++;
            }
        }
    }
    return comparisons;
}

int n_compar_opt (const std::vector<int>& A, const std::vector<int>& B) {
    int n = A.size();
    std::vector<int> C (n);
    for (int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++) C[i] = A[i] - B[i];
    std::sort (C.begin(), C.end());
    int comparisons = 0;
    int right_index = n-1;
    for (int left_index = 0; left_index < n; left_index++) {
        while ((right_index >= 0) && (C[left_index] > -C[right_index])) {
            right_index --;
        }
        comparisons += (n-1-right_index);
        if (right_index < left_index) comparisons --;  // to exclude the case i==j
    }
    comparisons /= 2;   // because pairs (i, j) have been counted twice
    return comparisons;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> A = {2, -4, -5, 8, 1, 13, 0, 2};
    std::vector<int> B = {5, 2, -2, -13, 0, 4, 7, 5};
    std::cout << "brute force: " << n_compar_bf (A, B) << "\n";
    std::cout << "new: " << n_compar_opt (A, B) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I understand what you are doing here, but in some cases it's giving wrong put such as this input case:
std::vector<int> A = {5,10,5, 7};
std::vector<int> B = {2, 4, 6, 8};

Comment: I corrected a mistake here: `if (right_index < left_index) comparisons --;`

Comment: while loop inside for loop is taking log n time here, right?

Comment: The right index will go from `n-1` to `0`. So, total complexity of the while loop is O(n).

Comment: Exactly, so won't the overall time complexity in this case be n^2 as well?

Comment: No: What is O(n) is the cumulative complexity of all the while loops. After the sorting, the total complexity is O(n).

Comment: Isn't this entire execution of for loop in worst case becoming  of the form 'n(n-1)/2' ?

Comment: It would be O(n^2) if the `right_index` were reinitialised to n-1 for each new value of `left_index`. It is not the case. It is basically one loop with two indices. You could look at one example in details to understand it. It is a rather classical and efficient scheme. I didn't invent it!

Comment: Oh yes now I get it, I don't know how I missed that part (that right_index wasn't reinitialized). Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4):

Rewriting the condition as `A[i] - B[i] > - (A[j] - B[j])`, you turn the problem to the detection of `C[i] > - C[j]`. After sorting, you easily solve this as a merge operation between the array `C` and the array `-C` inverted. (There is no need to invert explicitly, just adjust the indexes.) This is done in time Θ(N Log N), unless a faster sort is possible.

Answer (score 0):

I have done the following implementation now, but it seems to give 1 less than the ans in some cases, I can't figure out why. One such input case is included in this code.

```
#include <iostream>
    #include <algorithm> // for sort
    
    int count_comparisons(std::vector<int>& A, std::vector<int>& B) {
        int comparisons = 0;
    
        // define C as A[i] - B[i] for all i
        std::vector<int> C(A.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++) {
            C[i] = A[i] - B[i];
        }
    
        // sort C in ascending order
        std::sort(C.begin(), C.end());
    
        for (int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++) {
            // count the number of values C[j] to the right of i where C[i] > A[i] - B[i]
            int count = A.size() - (std::upper_bound(C.begin(), C.end(), -C[i+1]) - C.begin()) - 1;
            comparisons += count;
        }
    
        return comparisons/2;
    }
    
    
    int main() {
        std::vector<int> A = {5,10,5, 7};
        std::vector<int> B = {2, 4, 6, 8};
    
        int comparisons = count_comparisons(A, B);
        std::cout << "Number of comparisons: " << comparisons << std::endl;
    
        return 0;
    }
```